# Swift: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error in SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Ive been following a tutorial for helping me with a game I've been working on and everything had been running smoothly until I put in this function:

```
func generateCloud(seconds: NSTimeInterval) {
    let x = size.width / 2 * cloudWidth / 2
    let y = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(size.height))) - size.height / 2

    let cloud = MCTCloud(size: CGSizeMake(cloudWidth, cloudHeight))
    cloud.position = CGPointMake(x, y)
    addChild(cloud)
    }
```

and got an error with the green breakpoint in AppDelegate.swift stating the Thread 1: signal SIGABRT and looked into it further to find this:

```
2015-08-31 20:46:54.051 Test Runs[19662:1306631] -[Test_Runs.MCTCloudGen generateCloud]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe110c6d900         
2015-08-31 20:46:54.055 Test Runs[19662:1306631] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Test_Runs.MCTCloudGen generateCloud]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe110c6d900'    
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107a8dc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001099eebb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107a950ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001079eb13c ___forwarding___ + 988
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001079eacd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   Foundation                          0x000000010810a744 __NSFireTimer + 83
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001079f5174 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
7   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001079f4d35 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1045
8   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001079b6d3d __CFRunLoopRun + 1901
9   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001079b6366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
10  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010eed8a3e GSEventRunModal + 161
11  UIKit                               0x00000001087228c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
12  Test Runs                           0x00000001078877b7 main + 135
13  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a148145 start + 1
14  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Every time I run the game it just crashes and brings me back to the breakpoint in the AppDelegate file. Kinda lost and frustrated. Thanks for the help in advance.

**EDIT**
Here is the MCTCloud class:

```
class MCTCloud: SKShapeNode {
   init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init()
    let path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height), nil)
    self.path = path
    fillColor =
        UIColor.whiteColor()
    startMoving()


    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

}
 func startMoving() {
let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-10, y: 0, duration: 1)
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveLeft))

}
}
```

Comment: Its coming from a method you call with MCTCloud..... show us the class `MCTCloud`

Comment: :O I can't read that, put that in an edit to your post and format it plz :)

Comment: Trying to, gimme a sec.

Comment: huh... are you calling the method `generateCloud` anywhere? If not are you using standard Xcode with no plugins/extra 3rd party classes that could be affecting your code (you're using just the standard Sprite-Kit template)?

Comment: I don't think so...that may be it. Where (and how) would I call this? Sorry, kinda new, and yes I am using the standard template.

Comment: wait so you create that function but don't call it anywhere?

Comment: also where is that function? try to search the code and see where it else it is called or used

Comment: Yea, is that wrong? Would I call it somewhere in GameScene?

Comment: Searched my code and it hasn't been called anywhere.

Comment: Yeah that would be fine. And no its not wrong, just strange that Xcode is giving an error when the function isn't called at all. I used the code that you gave and tried to reproduce the error myself but it worked absolutely fine.

Comment: Huh...well im lost. Did you change anything?

Comment: nope, but I can offer some pointers to help you try to figure it out. first, add break points to identify the line that crashes it and figure out whats going on. You can also run Profiler in Xcode to see if something is going wrong. It could be that something is allocationg/deallocationg wrong and a method is being called on a wrong object as a result. I suspect it could be in another part of your code so look very carefully at everything

Comment: Ill try these things out. Thanks a bunch(:

Comment: No problem good luck!